# Django Quiz- fetching data from database onto specific website

Tags: python, html, django

I am having troubles fetching data from my data base. The quiz questions are unpopulated. Chat GPT considers the code for correct. Check if there is anything that interferes with them downloading the questions from the database and displaying them at questionmanager.html.

[image: Manager]

Please take a look and provide me with feedback:

## views.py

```
# Questions' deletion and edition in separate htmls & urls

class QuestionManagerView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "questionmanager.html"
    context_object_name = "questions"

    # Fetching data from database:
    def get_queryset(self):
        multi_questions = MultiQuesModel.objects.all()
        single_choice_questions = SingleChoiceQuestion.objects.all()
        text_questions = SingleQuestion.objects.all()

        # Debugging: Add print statements to check data
        print("Multi Questions:", multi_questions)
        print("Single Choice Questions:", single_choice_questions)
        print("Text Questions:", text_questions)

        return {"multi_questions": multi_questions, "single_choice_questions": single_choice_questions,
                "text_questions": text_questions}

    # Add this method to handle form submissions
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Process form data here

        # Debugging: Print form data
        answers_data = request.POST
        print("Form Data:", answers_data)

        # Validate the form
        form = YourFormHere(request.POST)
        print("Form is Valid:", form.is_valid())
        print("Form Errors:", form.errors)

        if form.is_valid():
            pass # Process the form data

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)  # Or redirect to another page


class DeleteMultiQuestionView(DeleteView):
    model = MultiQuesModel

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("question_manager")


class DeleteSingleQuestionView(DeleteView):
    model = SingleChoiceQuestion

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("question_manager")


class DeleteTextQuestionView(DeleteView):
    model = SingleQuestion

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("question_manager")

# Formulaire for text question form

class QuestionFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "formular.html"
    form_class = QuestionForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success_page')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Hier kannst du die Verarbeitung durchführen, wenn das Formular gültig ist
        # Nach der Verarbeitung erfolgt eine Umleitung zur Erfolgsseite
        form.save()  # Speichert die Frage und die Antwort in der Datenbank
        return super().form_valid(form)

# Adding multi-question creation  class view
# multiformular.html forms.py  class AddMultipleForm(forms.ModelForm): models.py class MultiQuesModel(models.Model): views.py class AddMultiQuestionView(View):
class AddMultiQuestionView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            form = AddMultipleForm()
            context = {"form": form}
            return render(request, "multiformular.html", context)
        else:
            return redirect("index")

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            form = AddMultipleForm(request.POST)
            print(request.POST)  # Hier printen Sie die POST-Daten
            print(form.is_valid())  # Hier printen Sie, ob das Formular gültig ist
            print(form.errors)  # Hier printen Sie eventuelle Formularfehler

            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()

                answers_data = form.cleaned_data["answers"]
                print(answers_data) # Hier printen Sie die geparsten Antwortdaten
                for answer_data in answers_data:
                    answer_text = answer_data["text"]
                    is_correct = answer_data["is_correct"]

                    answer, _ = Answer.objects.get_or_create(text=answer_text)
                    instance.answers.add(answer, through_defaults={"is_correct": is_correct})
                print("Preparing to redirect...")  # Hier wird geprintet, dass Sie sich auf die Weiterleitung vorbereiten
                return redirect("success_page")
            else:
                return render(request, "multiformular.html", {"form": form})
        else:
            return redirect("index")


# Page gets displayed once question is added successfully.
class SuccessPageView(View):
    template_name = "success_page.html"
    return_url = "question_manager"  # Verweist auf den Namen der URL "question_manager"

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(self.return_url))


# Single choice test
# --------------------------------
class AddSingleChoiceQuestionView(View):
    template_name = "single_choice_form.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = SingleChoiceQuestionForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            form = SingleChoiceQuestionForm(request.POST)
            print(request.POST)
            print(form.is_valid())
            print(form.errors)
            if form.is_valid():
                question = form.save()

                # Ermitteln Sie die ausgewählte Option aus den Checkboxen
                selected_option = int(request.POST.get("correct_option"))

                for i in range(1, 6):
                    option_text = request.POST.get(f"option_{i}")
                    is_correct = i == selected_option  # Überprüfen Sie, ob diese Option die ausgewählte ist
                    question.singlechoiceoption_set.create(option_text=option_text, is_correct=is_correct)

                # return HttpResponseRedirect("success_page") hier doesn't work
                return redirect("success_page")

            return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
        else:
            return redirect("index")
```

## questionmanager.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Question Manager</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style>
        body {
                font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
                background-color: rgba(179, 241, 245, 0.5);
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        </style>

        </head>

    <body>
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}

        <header>

            <h1 style="margin-right: 90px;">Questions' management</h1> <!-- Verschiebe "Questions" nach rechts -->

        </header>
<!-- Edition of questions -->
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Multiple Choice Questions</h2>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for question in questions.multi_questions %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ question.question }}</td>
                        <td>
{#                            <a href="{% url 'edit_single_question' question.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>#}
                            <a href="{% url 'edit_question' question_type='multi' pk=question.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'delete_multi_question' question.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Single Choice Questions</h2>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
{#                    {% for question in single_choice_questions %}#}
                    {% for question in questions.single_choice_questions %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ question.question_text }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{% url 'edit_single_question' question.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
{#                            <a href="{% url 'edit_question' question_type='single' pk=question.pk %}">Bearbeiten</a>#}
                            <a href="{% url 'delete_single_question' question.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Text Questions</h2>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for question in text_questions %}
{#                  {% for question in questions.text_questions %}#}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ question.question_text }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{% url 'edit_text_question' question.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'edit_question' question_type='text' pk=question.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Bearbeiten</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'delete_text_question' question.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

<!-- Edition of questions -->
    </body>
</html>
```

## models.py

```
# This class will be used for text question.
class SingleQuestion(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # Neues Feld für die Antwort

    language_name = models.ForeignKey(
        "Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )  # One to many relation; ForeignKey-Beziehung zu Category

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

# This class is needed for a dropdown selection of programming languages, which are added manually in the database with "+".
class Category(models.Model):
    language_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default="")  # One to many in Single Question

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language_name

class MultiQuesModel(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField("Answer", through="QuestionAnswer")
    language_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question


# Two fields possible
class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(MultiQuesModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# Single Choice question

class SingleChoiceQuestion(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class SingleChoiceOption(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(SingleChoiceQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.option_text
```

## forms.py

```
forms.py : 
 class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SingleQuestion
        fields = ["question_text", "language_name", "answer_text"]

    language_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())


# Multiple question form
# multiformular.html forms.py  class AddMultipleForm(forms.ModelForm): models.py class MultiQuesModel(models.Model): views.py class AddMultiQuestionView(View):
class AddMultipleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ans_count = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, label="Number of Answers Anzahl der Antworten")

    class Meta:
        model = MultiQuesModel
        fields = ["question", "language_name"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ans_count = self.initial.get("ans_count", 1)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # This code allows to write to the database all correct answers
        """
        In summary, below code attempts to extract the value for ans_count from the form data and if an error occurs,
        it simply keeps the predefined value ans_count. This allows the value for ans_count to be taken from the form
        data if it is available, or to use the default value if it is unavailable or invalid.
        """
        if self.data is not None:
            try:
                ans_count=int(self.data.get('ans_count', ans_count))
            except ValueError:
                pass
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        for i in range(ans_count):
            self.fields[f"answer_{i}"] = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
            self.fields[f"is_correct_{i}"] = forms.BooleanField(
                required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"class": "checkbox"})
            )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        ans_count = cleaned_data.get("ans_count")
        print(ans_count)
        answers = []

        for i in range(ans_count):
            answer_text = cleaned_data.get(f"answer_{i}")
            is_correct = cleaned_data.get(f"is_correct_{i}")

            if answer_text:
                answers.append({"text": answer_text, "is_correct": is_correct})

        if not answers:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Please fill out at least one answer. Bitte füllen Sie mindestens eine Antwort aus."
            )

        cleaned_data["answers"] = answers
        return cleaned_data


class SingleChoiceQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SingleChoiceQuestion
        fields = ["question_text", "language_name"]

    # options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    #     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=[(str(i), f"Option {i}") for i in range(1, 5)]
    # )

    options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False  # True makes an error
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["options"].choices = [(str(i), f"Option {i}") for i in range(1, 6)]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        selected_options = cleaned_data.get("options", [])

        # if len(selected_options) != 1:
        #     raise forms.ValidationError("Choose exactly one correct answer. Bitte wählen Sie genau eine richtige Antwort aus.")

        return cleaned_data
```